# PHP compare value from an Array in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array like this(trimmed) assigned to`$rows`:

```
array (size=9)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'room_category' => string 'MALE GENERAL WARD' (length=17)
      'vacant_beds' => string 'MG-8,MG-2,MG-4,MG-6,MG-7' (length=24)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'room_category' => string 'FEMALE GENERAL WARD' (length=19)
      'vacant_beds' => string 'FG-4,FG-1,FG-2,FG-3' (length=19)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'room_category' => string 'MOTHER CHILD WARD' (length=17)
      'vacant_beds' => string 'MC-2,MC-4,MC-5,MC-6' (length=19)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'room_category' => string 'TWIN' (length=4)
      'vacant_beds' => string 'TW-A1,TW-A2,TW-B2,TW-C1,TW-C2' (length=29)
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'room_category' => string 'NICU' (length=4)
      'vacant_beds' => string 'NICU-6,NICU-1,NICU-7,NICU-3,NICU-8,NICU-4,NICU-5' (length=48)
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      'room_category' => string 'CLASSIC' (length=7)
      'vacant_beds' => string 'CL-6,CL-8,CL-4,CL-5' (length=19)
  6 => 
    array (size=2)
      'room_category' => string 'DELUXE' (length=6)
      'vacant_beds' => string 'DLX-5,DLX-6' (length=11)
  7 => 
    array (size=2)
      'room_category' => string 'EXECUTIVE' (length=9)
      'vacant_beds' => null
  8 => 
    array (size=2)
      'room_category' => string 'AC GENERAL WARD' (length=15)
      'vacant_beds' => string 'AG-5,AG-1,AG-2,AG-3,AG-4' (length=24)
```

This array is saved in `$occupancies`

```
array (size=21)
  0 => 
    array (size=7)
      'room_name' => string 'CL-12' (length=5)
      'name' => string 'SHIBNATH PATEL' (length=14)
      'ipd' => string '0724/15' (length=7)
      'relation' => string '' (length=0)
      'mobile' => string '9178174433' (length=10)
      'district_city' => string 'SUNDARGARH' (length=10)
      'admission_date' => string '2015-06-15 11:30:00' (length=19)
  1 => 
    array (size=7)
      'room_name' => string 'AG-7' (length=4)
      'name' => string ' SHILPA GUPTA ' (length=14)
      'ipd' => string '0734/15' (length=7)
      'relation' => string 'D/0- PRADEEP KUMAR GUPTA ' (length=25)
      'mobile' => string '9937384641' (length=10)
      'district_city' => string 'SAMBALPUR' (length=9)
      'admission_date' => string '2015-06-15 13:45:00' (length=19)
```

Now I want to display the values in this array depending the matching of room_name in my foreach loop.

My code is like this:

```
$max_count = 0;
$new_rows =[];
foreach ($rows as $key=>$row){
    $elements=[];
    if(!empty($row['vacant_beds'])){
        $elements = explode(',',$row['vacant_beds']);

        if(sizeof($elements) > $max_count){
            $max_count = sizeof($elements);
        }
    }
    $new_rows[]= [
        'name'=>$row['room_category'],
        'elements'=>$elements,
    ];


}

foreach ($new_rows as $row){
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['name'] . '</td>';
        foreach($row['elements'] as $e){

      if ($occupancy['room_name']==$e) {
         echo "<td style='background-color:#CCFFFF;'>
        <div class='occupied'>MG-1<div id='occupied-hover'>       
        Patient Name - $occupancy_patient_name  <br> IPD No. - $occupancy_ipd 
        <br>          
        Guardian - $occupancy_relation <br> Mobile - $occupancy_mobile <br>
         Admission Date - $occupancy_admission_date        
        </div></div> </td>";

    }else{ 
      echo "<td style='background-color:#FFFFCC;'/>$e </td>";

    }
```

My question is how I can loop through the values in the `$rows` array to correctly display the array values in the above `foreach` iteration.

Comment: from your example 'vacant_beds' and 'room_category' aren't defined in the arrays.

Comment: you are right, I skipped that, updating it now.

Answer (score 0):

You're using some unnecessary iterations, Create a helper dict for the rooms where the key is the room's name:

```
$dict = array();
foreach($occupancies as $o)
    $dict[$o['room_name']] = $o; // if you can have more than one person per room you need to have an array here with $dict[$o['room_name']][] = $o;
```

Later you can use this dict to lookup for the info, for example :

```
if (isset($dict[$e])) { /* do the displaying work here */ }
```

Comment: I need to compare `$e` with the array `$rows[][`room_name`]` to display the value. can you elaborate a little how I can do that with your code.

Comment: when using a dict , you have $rows[][room_name] directly at $dict[room_name]

Comment: if I am doing a `var_dump($dict['room_name']);` I am getting undefined index.